Cannot set custom image in ControlWidgetButton (Control Center Widget)
I implemented a simple control center widget for iOS18 but I cannot find a way to correctly render my image in the control.
This is my code:
@available(iOS 18.0, *)
struct ShortcutControlWidget: ControlWidget {

    private let kind: String = "shortcut"
    private let name = LocalizedStringResource(stringLiteral: "key1")
    
    public var body: some ControlWidgetConfiguration {
        StaticControlConfiguration(kind: kind) {
            ControlWidgetButton(action: OpenShortcutIntent()) {
                Label("key1" image: "image1")
            }
        }
        .displayName(name)
    }
}

I already have a lockscreen widget that correctly displays Image("image1") without issues in this same extension. I tried other initialisers for for Label but the result is always this control with a ? symbol:

I am on iOS 18 beta 7 and building with Xcode 16.0.0-Beta.6.

ControlWidgetButton implements ControlWidgetTemplate which is documented to only support symbol images (although this worked in beta 3).

These templates define images (specifically, symbol images) [...]

I have transformed my images to custom symbols and it worked.
